# Как получить виджет по координатам? (Qt, c++)

Tags: c++, qt

Приветствую. Я разрабатываю перетаскиваемые вкладки для MDI приложения, как в `Chrome` или `Visual Studio`. Для этого я составил такие условия:

1. Если в `QTabBar` > 1 вкладки, тогда при перетаскивании вкладки за пределы `QTabBar` она становится окном, при помощи `setParent(nullptr);` и продолжает перемещаться за курсором мыши пока мы не отпустим левую кнопку.
2. Если в `QTabBar` 1 вкладка, то при перетаскивании за вкладку, у нас просто перемещается окно.
3. Если при перетаскивании окна методом описанном в п. 2, мы перетащили вкладку на какой либо `QTabBar`, окно становится вкладкой внутри этого `QTabBar`.

Также следует отметить, что окон и вкладок может быть неограниченное количество. И приложение кроссплатформенное.

Мне удалось реализовать первые 2 условия, но решить 3 я не могу уже несколько дней. 
**Вопрос**: Как определить, что при перетаскивании окна(как в п. 2) мы попали в область `QTabBar`? Либо как сделать, чтобы `QTabBar`, к которому мы переместили вкладку получил событие? Что вы можете посоветовать для реализации 3 пункта?

Сложность заключается в том, что я не могу использовать метод `widgetAt();`, т.к. при перетаскивании он всегда будет возвращать указатель на вкладку, а не на виджет под окном(нужный мне `QTabBar`).

## Проведенное исследование

Для того, чтобы ловить событие наведения мыши в `QTabBar`, я пробовал такие методы, которые, тем не менее не подошли:

- `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, true);` для того, чтобы верхнее окно пропускало события сквозь себя. Работает только для виджетов в одном окне.
- `event->ignore();` опять же, для того, чтобы пропускать событие. Действует аналогично вышесказанному.
- Класс `QHoverEvent` для того, чтобы виджет получал события, даже если перекрыт другим. Не подходит, т.к. работает только в одном окне.

Ручной перебор, как советовал @isnullxbh, всех областей(через `QTabBar::rect()->contains(mouse->globalPos())`) тоже не совсем подходит, т.к. затратен по ресурсам и возникают проблемы, если окна с `QTabBar'ами` накладываются друг на друга.

Comment: А что если спросить у каждого окна childAt? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#childAt

Comment: @Unick, нет, это не то. Проблема в том, что мне нужно узнать находится ли курсор мыши на виджете, в тот момент, когда он перекрыт другим виджетом.

Comment: Лень регаться на оф.сайте Qt, но вдруг Вам нет: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50024-Drag-n-drop-Tab-inside-and-outside-the-Main-Application

Comment: @isnullxbh зарегался, скачал. Сайт не официальный же. Там проект под старую версию Qt, завтра переделаю на новую, отпишу.

Comment: @Nik, ждем-с !)

Comment: @isnullxbh, переписал, потестил, но там не очень функционал. Там вкладки при перетаскивании сначала становятся уменьшенной миниатюрой(т.е. мы перетаскиваем просто картинку), а уже когда отпускаем, появляется окно. Но это ладно. Там нельзя перетянуть окно к панели вкладок - окно становится вкладкой только если его закрыть. Соответственно вкладки с `QTabBar` есть только в главном окне, дочерние окна - это просто окна. А нужно бы стакать вкладки еще и внутри дочерних окон, т.е. чтобы в дочерних окнах тоже был QTabBar к которому можно перетягивать другие окна.

Comment: А разве там нельзя порождать окна, аналогичные родительскому ?

Comment: @isnullxbh Порождать то при желании можно, только смысл? Там все устроено так, что окно может стать вкладкой только при закрытии. То есть все дочерние окна при закрытии становятся вкладками 1 родительского окна.

Comment: Ну да..(
Ладно, посмотрите еще сырцы у Amarok'a - плеер такой. может слышали ? Говорят, там есть что-то подобное, с вкладками.

Comment: @isnullxbh, похоже единственный способ - опрашивать все `QTabBar->geometry()->contains(mouse->globalPos())`. Я сейчас посмотрел исходник функции `widgetAt()` там по циклу идет перебор, и тоже через `contains()`. Буду таким способом делать. Если интересно, могу как доделаю кинуть ссылку на github.

Comment: Да, было бы интересно посмотреть. ВК есть в профиле, icq: 703857675

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте получить все виджеты QWindow: `QObject::findChildren<QWidget*>()`. Для приведения к QObject используйте `qobject_cast<ptrT>(...)`.
А затем пройдитесь по полученному списку и проверьте принадлежность данной точки M(x,y) каждому из элементов полученного списка.

Comment: Дело в том, что окон может быть 20, и находить все виджеты, находить координаты каждого будет слишком дорого по производительности.

Comment: Тогда имеем следующую ситуацию - у нас несколько окон, они принадлежат одному приложению. Курсор мыши находится на некоторой позиции. В итоге: в первом окне под курсором какой-нибудь список, во втором - поле ввода и т.д. И Вам хотелось бы получить указатели всех этих виджетов ?

Comment: Если так, то пройдитесь по этим окнам, и вызовете метод findChild

Comment: в идеале, я бы хотел получить указатель на виджет, находящийся слоем ниже, чем виджет, который возвратила функция `widgetAt();` то есть, чтобы `widgetAt();` как бы проигнорировал один слой.

Comment: Уверен на 99% что в фреймворке нет встроенных решений для такого рода задач. Слишком специфично. Чем Вам не нравится вышеупомянутый вариант ? Получить список окон в своем-то коде - не проблема, а дальше findChild все сделает за Вас.

Comment: ну смотрите, `widgetAt();` ведь пропускает невидимые виджеты, значит можно как-то сделать, чтобы он пропускал виджеты по определенному признаку. Ваш вариант хорош, но слишком мощный для такой простой задачи.

Comment: Ну подумайте сами, если было бы встроенное решение, как бы оно было реализованно ?)) И я не совсем понимаю, почему это "тяжело". Я не спорю с Вами, и не говорю в упрек. Мне просто самому интересно. Ваши окна ведь имеют общего родителя, почему тогда тяжело проверить его дочерние элементы ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44522/discussion-between-nik-and-isnullxbh).